# How to use API Gateway without increasing latency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have 3 microservices (REST API): s1, s2 and s3. I would like to create an API Gateway to expose some actions to the frontend.

So, the API Gateway should look like:

- /action1 -> s1/action1
- /action2 -> s2/action2
- /action3 -> 1) s1/action1 + 2) s2/action2

It is possible to link /action1 with s1/action1, but how do I use several services in the same endpoint? If I do a lambda function for /action3, I would have to manually call both APIs and there will be an extra time (latency) to perform the request.

What am I missing? is this a good design?

Edit:

Just trying to understand how to implement the API Gateway pattern in AWS API Gateway. This is what I don't really understand:

> The API Gateway can also provide each client with a custom API. It
> typically exposes a coarse‑grained API for mobile clients. Consider,
> for example, the product details scenario. The API Gateway can provide
> an endpoint (/productdetails?productid=xxx) that enables a mobile
> client to retrieve all of the product details with a single request.
> **The API Gateway handles the request by invoking the various services –
> product info, recommendations, reviews, etc. – and combining the
> results.**

[Link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/)

Comment: What do you mean by "use several services in the same endpoint"? If a request `/action3/apple` comes in, which path should API gateway route to?

Comment: I want to create an API Gateway for my services. This is not a problem when there is a direct mapping: apigateway/action1 -> service1/action1.
But, I don't know how to combine results: api/gateway/action2 -> service1/action1 + service2/action2. Another example: service1/action1 returns 10 fields, how do I implement apigateway/action1 calling service1/action1 to return 5 fields?

Comment: API Gateway is only a gateway, it doesn't "do" anything, and combining results would count very much as "doing" something. You'll need a 3rd "action" that "does" the combining, and just use API Gateway to invoke it.

Comment: So, if I want to implement [API composition](https://miro.medium.com/max/651/1*5r0t_UNF_xVQ9uwv3V_xIQ.png), I have to link my API Gateway with a Lambda function. That Lambda function must perform the "composition" (call service1, service 2 and combining the result). Is this right?